# How to check Grails Rest Client returned contenttype

Tags: spring, rest, grails, grails-3.0

I am using the Grails RestClient to test JSON API for completeness i would like to check on the returntype of a request.

Is there a better way then going like this:

```
response.responseEntity.headers.getContentType().toString() == "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

The responseEntity is a [ResponseEntity](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) java class from the spring-framework so nothing **groovy** about it.

Considering this, looking at their own [tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/test/java/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntityTests.java) we can see that they essentially do just what you do:

```
MediaType contentType = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN;
...
HttpHeaders responseHeaders = responseEntity.getHeaders();
...
assertEquals(contentType.toString(), responseHeaders.getFirst("Content-Type"));
```

One thing they do slightly sifferent is use a `MediaType` constant; there is a `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` that has the value of `application/json` and with json's default encoding already being UTF-8, you could remove this from the content-type (if you have control).